# navigation drawer bottom right icon android

Tags: android, navigation, icons, drawer

I have adapted the navigation drawer with an icon in my appliccation as shown in the figure1, it seems ok. 
I want to have the icon on the right bottom side of my menu as google maps did.

[image: figure1]
[image: figure2]

**code:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    setupSlideMenu();
}

private void setupSlideMenu() {
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout1);
    addIcon();
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer1);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mPlanetTitles));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    log("setupSlideMenu", false);
}

private void addIcon() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    this,                   /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout,          /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer,   /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.drawer_open,   /* "open drawer" description */
    R.string.drawer_close   /* "close drawer" description */
    ) {
        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        }
    };
    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
      return true;
    }
    // Handle your other action bar items...
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use [BottomDrawerToggle](http://github.com/NikolaDespotoski/DrawerLayoutToggles/tree/master/src/com/nikola/despotoski/drawerlayouttoggles).
Solution was pretty simple:

1. Added `ImageView` to the android.R.id.content FrameLayout with gravity BOTTOM
2. Made `ImageView` half visible by setting right/left margin to negative value of the half of it's drawable width.
3. Resolved internal resource `action_bar_icon_vertical_padding` and used it as bottom padding of the image view

   ```
   int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_icon_vertical_padding", "dimen", "android");
   float padding = mActivity.getResources().getDimension(id);
   ```
4. Created `SlidingDrawable` and calculated how to dynamically hide the the drawable as the drawer slides in/out in `draw(Canvas canvas)` method. Drawable is hid by clipping the `Rect` with drawer's amount of visible pixels.

   ```
   public void draw(Canvas canvas)
   {
     float pixelsVisible = mOffset * mMinusShadow;
     int target = (int) ((mWrapped.getIntrinsicWidth()/2)+pixelsVisible);
     if(mGravity == GravityCompat.START || mGravity == Gravity.LEFT)
         canvas.clipRect(target, 0, mWrapped.getIntrinsicWidth(), mWrapped.getIntrinsicHeight());
     else
         canvas.clipRect(0, 0, mWrapped.getIntrinsicWidth() - target,mWrapped.getIntrinsicHeight());       
     this.mWrapped.draw(canvas);
     canvas.restore();
   }
   ```